# iTunes crash logs with "dyld message: Library not loaded..."

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've received a crash log in iTunes for:

```
Dyld Message: Library not loaded: @rpath/Foo.framework/Foo
```

There are several of these, each for a different framework that is included in the app, although there isn't one for *every* framework.

I understand what a "library not loaded" crash means, and how to fix one that is happening on every run of the app - it's just "add the framework to copy files, because you forgot to before". My impression is an app should either crash with this error *every time* it is run, or  *none* of the times it is run - either the framework is included in the bundle, or it isn't.

A few more details:

- I can't reproduce this, and the vast majority of users seem to be getting along fine.
- There are crash reports for both workspace (normal "Copy Files") and Carthage (`carthage copy-frameworks`) frameworks.

What should I do to investigate and fix these crashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to happen when the device itself runs too low on memory. It's an iOS bug that should be fixed in iOS 9.3.2 (released May 16, 2016). The users that experience have many apps crashing for them during launch. The only way they can solve it is by restarting their device.

The issue is caused by apps using too many (third party) Frameworks. So you can either remove Frameworks (by for example copying third party code into your project) or wait for users to get the iOS update with the fix.

Comment: How do you know the issue is caused by using too many third-party frameworks? Does it seem to be a hard or a soft cap?

Comment: Apple acknowledged that this was the problem. I don't know what the cap was. But now that 9.3.2 has been released it shouldn't be much of an issue anymore as long as your users update their iOS.

Comment: Could you share a link to where Apple acknowledge the issue?

Comment: Their Developer Technical Support team informed me by email:

_"Thank you for attaching that crash log. This is a known bug in iOS that seems to be related to the number of embedded frameworks apps have. If you can reduce the number of embedded frameworks your app has, you may reduce the chance of your users hitting this bug. However, if your app uses Swift, your app would still need to have a number of embedded frameworks.

Your best course of action might be to wait for an iOS update to fix this bug."_